# Optimize perl script to filter rows based on date in the file

Tags: perl, date, optimization

I am a beginner with programming not just perl ! 
Please let me know what needs to change or how else this can be done.

Need to optimize the perl code to run faster. 
For a test run, with around a 500MB file with 3 million rows in it, runtime is 28 minutes.

I know a tool which processes the 39 million rows in 15 mins, but i want to acheive this running on the command prompt without resorting to the tool.

Earlier I used Date::Manip and Date::Parse and moved on to DateTime, thinking it should be faster.

My approach was If the dates are ISO-8601 (ie, YYYY-MM-DD) and we do not need to validate them, 
we can compare lexicographically (ie, the lt and gt operators.)

- Input File Date Format is 07/18/2013 13:45:49
- Input File Size 42GB.
- Number of Rows 39 Million.
- Column Delimiter : |~|
- Platform :   GNU/Linux

I have tried ">" and "gt" and did not find any difference in runtime.

```
Code snippet:

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $idate = "07/17/2013 00:00:00";

my $Strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
                   pattern     => '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                  );

my $inputdt = $Strp->parse_datetime($idate);

open (FILE,"myinputfile.dat") or die "could not input File\n";
while (defined(my $line = <FILE>)) {
    my @chunks = split '[|]~[|]', $line;
    my $fdate = $Strp->parse_datetime($chunks[6]);
    if ( $fdate > $inputdt) {
    open(FILEOUT, ">>myoutputfile.dat") or die "Could not write\n";
    print FILEOUT "$line";
                         }
}
close(FILE);
close (FILEOUT);
```

Comment: why is your perl code (when you are a beginner) that oldschool?

Comment: Have you tried taking the 'if' out temporarily to see what your run time is?  Also, you might take a look at: https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::NYTProf#SYNOPSIS

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I did not know it was oldschool. I'll come back to it after seeking a solution for the current issue.

Comment: Why open the output file each time you find a match?

Comment: And btw: Yes, Paulchenkiller is absolutely correct and his question is valid. What books/tutorials/whatever are you using? Newcomers shouldn't be coding in this style in 2013.

Comment: What does a row look like?  Is it 07/18/2013 13:45:49|~|and|~|some|~|other|~|data ??

Comment: Here's one book, freely available, that will probably help you:  http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_00.html  I'm also a fan of Ovid's "Beginning Perl": http://amzn.com/1118013840

Comment: No one's to blame, the code is cooked up by looking at the examples in stackoverflow. For my learning I used videos at ScriptSocket. @innaM So should I move the open file statement to an earlier line and then just redirect each rows as it validates to true?

Comment: @Craig Treptow - The row would be as you summed up, just that the date is never the first field/column.

Comment: user2435192: open the file before entering the while-loop and then simply print to it when you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two and a half big performance problems here:

1. You open the output file in every iteration. Just open it once, before the loop.
2. The `parse_datetime` returns a DateTime object. Object orientation with Perl implies a significant overhead. Because your pattern is well defined, we can do the parsing ourself, and remove all object orientation.
3. Reading a file in the GB range just takes some time. To speed this up, upgrade your hardware (e.g. to a SSD).

To parse the date string into a sortable representation, we just reorder the various parts to a string:

```
# %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S → %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
$fdate =~ s{^ ([0-9]{2} / [0-9]{2}) / ([0-9]{4}) }{$2/$1}x;

if ($fdate gt $inputdate) { ... }
```

This would lead to the code

```
use strict; use warnings;

use constant DATE_FIELD => shift @ARGV;

my $inputdate = shift @ARGV;
$inputdate =~ s{^ ([0-9]{2} / [0-9]{2}) / ([0-9]{4}) }{$2/$1}x;

<>; # remove the header line

while (<>) {
    my $filedate = (split /\|~\|/, $_, DATE_FIELD + 2)[DATE_FIELD];
    $filedate =~ s{^ ([0-9]{2} / [0-9]{2}) / ([0-9]{4}) }{$2/$1}x;
    print if $filedate gt $inputdate;
}
```

The in- and output, as well as the start date, are specified on the command line, e.g.

```
./script 6 '07/17/2013 00:00:00' myinputfile.dat >>myoutputfile.dat
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your inputs, I think you meant $inputdate instead of $inputdt on the if statement. I changed it. I will update how it goes.

Comment: Either `$filedate` or `$inputdate` is not defined so either the date on the command line or the regex is failing to give one of them a value. Check you have all your `;` too :-)

Comment: I maybe be too slavishly devoted to CPAN, but might this benefit from `Regexp::Common` ?

Comment: @amon - Works like magic on the 500 MB file (10 Secs may be). My input file has a header as the first row, which is also making it to the output file. How can i stop that ? I am testing the 42 GB file and will update you with the runtime. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2435192 you can read the first line outside the loop to discard it, see my edit.

Comment: @amon - This should be the last one, my filedate filed changes across the inputfiles, so the line with the split command with [6] is that what I would change? The 42 gb file has date in 8th feild. When I change that to 8 I have Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at

Comment: @user2435192 The 3rd argument to `split` can limit the number of resulting fragments, which I included here as an optimization. You can now specify the column for the date as the first argument on the command line.

Comment: Runtime is under 6mins for the 42 GB file withover 39 million rows. Thank you so much @amon. I will need to pick up some perl skils.